# Merge NUnit and NAnt output in build report

Tags: c#, nunit, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I've just started using CruiseControl.NET and I'm having trouble understanding why the merging of NAnt and NUnit outputs are not working.  I've setup my `ccnet.config` with typical values as found on google:

```xml
<merge>
  <files>
    <file>D:\ccnet\path1\nant-results.xml</file>
    <file>D:\ccnet\path2\TestResult.xml</file>
  </files>
</merge>
<xmllogger />
```

NAnt and ccnet are half working: if I deliberately put in a code error, then ccnet will say the build has failed. The same happens if I deliberately put in a failing test: ccnet will say build failed.

**The problem** is that the `ViewBuildReport.aspx` page does not show any of the output from NAnt or NUnit.

Obviously I must be missing something, but I don't know what. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Albert - I found the answer by accident some time after asking.  It seems that this is ccnet's behavior *out of the box*.  So by default it does not show the compile results in the web dashboard.

You need to locate the file \CruiseControl.NET\webdashboard\dashboard.config and in the buildReportBuildPlugin section, add compile.xsl.  It will look like this when added:

```
<buildPlugins>
  <buildReportBuildPlugin>
    <xslFileNames>
      <xslFile>xsl\header.xsl</xslFile>
      <xslFile>xsl\unittests.xsl</xslFile>
      <xslFile>xsl\modifications.xsl</xslFile>
      <xslFile>xsl\NCoverSummary.xsl</xslFile>

      <xslFile>xsl\compile.xsl</xslFile>

    </xslFileNames>
  </buildReportBuildPlugin>
  <buildLogBuildPlugin />
  <xslReportBuildPlugin description="NCover Report" actionName="NCoverBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\NCover.xsl"></xslReportBuildPlugin>
</buildPlugins>
```

The documentation was extremely bad, and I only found this by accident when looking for something else.  I was not happy that I wasted so much time when a little documentation or an example on the ccnet site would have solved this in minutes.

Comment: After making this change, run iisreset to restart iis for the changes to take effect.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Is that block located in your publishers section?

Here's what one of my publishers looks like:

```
    <publishers>
        <merge>
            <files>
                <file>*-results.xml</file>
            </files>
        </merge>
        <xmllogger />
    </publishers>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had missed the publishers tag, but adding it did not fix anything.

What is the best practice for calling nant and nunit from ccnet?  Currently I have this setup that I don't like:

ccnet with nant task, and the nant build file uses msbuild and nunit2 tasks to compile and test.

Its hard to find a decent example of ccnet, nant and nunit that really explains the best way to use them all together.  I am running ccnet as a service, does that make a difference?  I'm trying to keep it as simple as I can, this is roughly what I'm doing:

ccnet.config:

```
<tasks>
<nant>
<baseDirectory>D:\ccnet\builds\checkout\path</baseDirectory>
<buildFile>go.build</buildFile>
<targetList>
<target>test</target>
</targetList>
</nant>
</tasks>

<publishers>
<merge>
<files>
<file>D:\ccnet\builds\artifacts\path1\nant-results.xml</file>
<file>D:\ccnet\builds\checkout\path\name.dll-results.xml</file>
</files>
</merge>
<xmllogger /> 
</publishers>
```

And in go.build:

```
<target name="build" depends="clean">
<msbuild project="name.sln">
</msbuild>
</target>

<target name="test" depends="build">
<nunit2>
<formatter type="Xml" usefile="false" />
<test assemblyname="Tests\path\name.dll" />
</nunit2>
</target>
```

If I check the build log from the dashboard, then I can see that it does have the xml output from both nant and nunit. But this is not shown on the dashboard itself, why would that be?  This is getting to be very frustrating...

I have tried two different types of approach: The auto-magic ccnet approach (just set usefile="false" and let ccnet do its thing).  This did not work.

I also tried the manual approach, set usefile="true" and then merge the nant-results.xml and name.dll-results.xml files (no wildcards, just using the exact path to the file which I have triple checked.)

It just does not make any sense at all

Comment: If you call MsBuild from NAnt, then, why don't you just drop NAnt, and use MSBuild directly ?  You can call MSBuild directly from cc.net.

Comment: I could be doing it wrong, thats why :)  The idea was to have one nant script that can be run from ccnet and to also be able to run the same script as a pre check-in script (to make sure no one checks in stuff that breaks the build).  Still doesnt explain why no output is shown in the dashboard.

Comment: As far as I can see, this page here: <http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/NAnt%20Task.html> says that Nant output will be rendered by default (as per the section "NAnt output in Xml").  But it doesnt say anything about what to do when the nant output is not shown.

The same url also has a section "NUnit and NAnt", that appears to say that if you use the usefile="false" attribute of nunit2, then again the xml will be automatically parsed.  But this is also not happening for me.